# Graphql post body "Must provide query string."

Tags: express, graphql, postman, graphql-js

I use Express-graphql middleware.
I send the following request in the body line:

```
POST /graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: local:8083
Content-Type: application/graphql
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d71a7ea9-5502-d5fe-2e36-0ae49c635a29

{
   testing {
      pass(id: 1) {
        idn
      }
    }
}
```

and have error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must provide query string."
    }
  ]
}
```

in graphql i can send update in URL.

URL string is too short. i must send update model like

```
mutation {
  update(id: 2, x1: "zazaza", x2: "zazaza", x3: "zazaza" ...(more more fields)...) {
    idn
  }
}
```

I think its must be in request body. How can I send 'update' query or that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "in graphql i can send update in URL." <-- Do you mean `graphiql`?

Comment: i'm use "postman" to send request.

Comment: you need to change "Content type" in postman's headers to "application/json" and in request body use "GraphQL" tab with "query" and "graphql variables"

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Post request needs to manage headers info.

1. Using Http client - `Content-Type`: `application/json`
2. Using Postman client - `Content-Type`: `application/graphql`

but request body looks like string

```
{"query":"mutation{update(id:1,x1:\"zazaz\",x2:\"zazaz\"......){id x1 x2}}"}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using graphql and want to test it using postman or any other Rest client do this.

In postman, select `POST` method and enter your `URL` and set `Content-Type` as `application/graphql` then pass your query in the body.

Example:

```
http://localhost:8080/graphql
Mehtod: POST
Content-Type: application/graphql
Body: 
  query{
    FindAllGames{
    _id
    title
    company
    price
    year
    url
   }
 }
```

Thats it you will get the response.

[image]

Comment: what is that request tester you are using?

Answer (score 7):

Using Postman Version **7.2.2** I had a similar issue. This version of Postman supports Graphql out of the box. Changing the Content-type to `application/json` fixed it for me.

[image: Image showing the Content-type in Postman]

Answer (score 6):

This generally occurs when your 'express-graphql' doest receive any params. You need to added a json/applicaton parser in your application.

```sh
npm install body-parser
```

eg -

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json
```

Comment: where the hell does bodyParser come from, common, be thorough here, what lib?

Comment: @PositiveGuy, you can `npm install body-parser --save` and then `import bodyParser from 'body-parser'`;

Answer (score 5):

for me worked like as following:

In the body

[image: Body postman]

In the Headers

[image: Header postman]

Don't forget mark GraphQl [x] on Body settings

[image]

And how was quoted before changes the verb to POST.

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: POST was what I was missing on mine.  Thanks - saved the day for me too!

Answer (score 3):

1. go to the relevant web page and open "inspect" (by write click ->
   inspect || Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome)
2. go to the network tab and copy the cURL command
   [image]
3. open the postman ,then import -> raw text
4. paste the copied command
   [image]
5. then,continue ->

[image]

Comment: This works fine and should be the easiest!!!

Comment: Thanks, your menthod helped me to find a root cause of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73788400/3722635

Answer (score 1):

Switch content type to JSON.
Like this [image: see Postman image]

Comment: Please provide some comment for your answer.

Comment: its not JSON. its only "query" : "graphQL query string", its not correct. We must send valid JSON but cant do this

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using correct protocol in your Postman requests.

I used **HTTP** instead of **HTTPS** and this caused the same error.

Changes of `content-type`, `raw` or `json` instead of `graphql` type didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error coming out of a test I was writing, and when I looked into it further, I found that I was the only one in the codebase who had ever tried using the homemade test harness's method for changing variables... and that method did not work.

The test literally wasn't sending a query string. Just mentioning in case others encounter a similar issue.